# Play sbt Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have a Play application in an SBT project and I just integrated the Hibernate validator but it gives me a huge load of debug logging. I want to change the log level. My project has the typical play/sbt architecture :

```
project
---app
---conf
---project
---target
---test
---build.sbt
```

I checked hibernate dependencies it seems to use log4j. Does anyone nows what file I have to create and where to put it ? In the debug logs it seems to look for META-INF/validation.xml if it tells you something.

Answer (score 0):

In config file specify the log level for hibernate.
F.E. in `application.conf` file

```
logger.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

or specify package exactly 
F.E.

```
logger.org.hibernate.<pack_level_1><.pack_level_2><.ClassName>=ERROR
logger.org.hibernate.validator=ERROR
```

Comment: unfortunately no it does not seem to work. Not that I am using the Validator inside a class directly, not as a dependency of the play framework, it may make it difficult to give it configuration